# vue js converting a map filter to a variable

Tags: vue.js

```js
const managers = new Map([

    ['CA1111@domain.com', 'myuser@domain.com'],
    ['SA5363@domain.com', 'auser@domain.com'],
    ['EA6373@domain.com', 'theuser@domain.com']


    ])
    
    Vue.filter('managers', function(value)  {   
                return (value != null ? managers.get(value.substring(0, 10)) : "") || 'Unknown' 
            })
```

I am using vue 2.5 and I have a .map filter I am using to point to a specific email address of a user. The issue is- I want to be able to point this in a variable format and I am trying to figure out the best way to achieve this. So the correct email address displays on the screen due to a "filter", but I need this to be pushed to a variable?

```
{{sillystring | manager}}
```

Comment: Not really clear, what you want to achieve. Could you also show the result arrangement? (Like doing it manually)

Comment: I know sllyString is vm.Sillystring

Comment: manager is a filter

Comment: is there a way to write vm.SillyString.filter(Manager);

Comment: i just need the same functionality to be akin to a variable as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `filter` to get that result. And you don't need a `filter`, if you want your code to be future-proof (Vue3 drops the `filter`s: https://dev.to/chenxeed/awesome-breaking-changes-in-vue-3-if-you-migrate-from-vue-2-3b98)

```js
const managers = new Map([
  ['CA1111@domain.com', 'myuser@domain.com'],
  ['SA5363@domain.com', 'auser@domain.com'],
  ['EA6373@domain.com', 'theuser@domain.com']
])

Vue.filter('managers', function(value) {
  return (value != null ? managers.get(value.substring(0, 17)) : "") || 'Unknown'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    managerList: []
  },
  methods: {
    managers(value) {
      // putting the values into a list
      if (!this.managerList.includes(value)) {
        this.managerList = [...new Set([...this.managerList, value])]
      }

      // returning value like a filter
      return (value != null ? managers.get(value.substring(0, 17)) : "") || 'Unknown'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  "managers" filter: {{ "SA5363@domain.com" | managers }}<br />
  "managers" method: {{ managers("SA5363@domain.com") }}<br />
  "managers" method: {{ managers("EA6373@domain.com") }}<br />
  "managerList" attribute: {{ managerList }}
</div>
```

Actually your example code wouldn't work, as you want a `value` in a `Map` with `substring` of length 10, but the `Map`'s keys are 17 chars long. Maybe this is just because of the example, but I had to correct that to make the snippet work.

Comment: the code i had above works fine. What i need is simple way to get that data to a variable.. i do not care about future proofing.

Comment: @Vzupo then sorry, but I don't see where you're going. What data in what variable? I don't think I can help more until I understand the goal. With the example you gave, AFAIK it's easier just to create a variable with the value `"Unknown"`.

Comment: on the screen--i get the correct information presented which is a filtered down email

Comment: my code works fine. What i need is to be able to make this be assigned to a simple variable..because I am using the filtered email elsewhere

Comment: so is there anyway to assign this {{sillystring | manager}} to a variable

Comment: @Vzupo I still suggest that you ditch the `filter` for a `method` - it's not a coincidence that Vue development deprecates that. With a `method` you can get everything, what a filter does, and do anything with the data in addition. If you look at my snippet, the `managers` method does what the filter does, and also puts the filtered value in a "secure place" (so you can use it elsewhere). I'm pretty sure this is the way to go. If you want to use it globally, then you can put that in a `mixin` (for example), and make that global (or import it where you use it)

Comment: i went a different route and just assigned the .text to a variable--it gives me what I need. a far simple-basic solution.